# Recovering MySQL 5.7 tables in MariaDB10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, data-recovery

I did a very foolish thing... I did not realize installing mariaDB would uninstall MYSQL 5.7 using apt-get.  (Using Ubuntu 16.04).

So now I am trying to recover my data.

So far, I have read many guides and tried several things.

My most successful attempt is 
1) Fresh install of MaraiDB, copy * files from old sql directory to new.
2) Copy database directory myDatabase/ from old sql directory to new.
3) Run mysql_secure_installation
4) Configure my users, etc. etc.

This works except that I cannot run sql queries.

```
SELECT * FROM myDatabase.tableOne;
```

I get either:

```
SQL Error [1932] [42S02]: (conn:56) Table 'AMS_test.AMZ_adGroups' doesn't exist in engine
```

OR

```
SQL Error [1146] [42S02]: (conn:56) Table 'AMS_test.AMZ_ads' doesn't exist
```

depending on which table I call (tableOne gives first error, tableTwo the second error..)

So far, I have read that mysqlcheck can fix this.

If I run

```
/var/lib/mysql$ mysqlcheck myDatabase
myDatabase.tableOne
Error    : Table 'myDatabase.tableOne' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
```

I can't find any suggested solutions for fixing this.
Although perhaps I went the wrong way from the beginning.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: i advice you to post on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: THank you for the suggestion.  Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217963/recovering-mysql-5-7-tables-in-mariadb-10